# Creating a RESTful api for my Ionic app

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, ionic-framework

I have created an Ionic app which uses pouchdb to store items locally and then syncs them with remotely with couchdb

I am looking to create a REST api for this app which uses the items stored in my couchdb from the app. A web app will also show all of the items from the mobile ionic app.

I have experience with Node using Express. Would node/express be the best/easiest thing to use when building the api build? Or is there another much simpler more popular way?

Comment: You can use Node with Express that is totally fine, and at this point of time you almost everything will take same amount of time. Though You must be sure what database you are willing to use, depends most of it in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Firebase https://firebase.google.com/, it' a mobile platform that helps you quickly develop high-quality apps

Answer (score 0):

If you're not completely set on using NoSQL on your API, you should really take a look at [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/).

If you can map your data to objects, I'm sure you can go from zero knowledge to having an API up in hours. The quickstart tutorial is fully functional and you can set that up in just minutes! Plus, having more frameworks and languages under your belt can only be a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Node client which you can use in your `Expresss` server for Couch DB called [`Nano`](https://www.google.co.zw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjoi7S8lpbPAhWBsxQKHQSOBAAQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdscape%2Fnano&usg=AFQjCNFe4hrAT1FXmojpAQgwzGywBfyN4Q&sig2=uWEK5gwxwigCOe0A_0EzmA) , just like you would use `mongoose` for dealing with `MongoDB` . Since CouchDB already provides the ability to retrieve data using http, so you can even use an http wrapper like `request` but you can use `Nano` for a higher level abstraction.

You can then go ahead build an API that simply proxies those requests to your CouchDB instance.